# Inherit properties from one RadialGradientBrush to another

Tags: wpf, xaml

### Issue

I am attempting to write a style/theme for an application
This is based of a mergedResourceDisctionary
My intention is to inherit dynamic resources from an existing Base Dynamic resource of the same type, in this case

STAC_RGrad_Status_Base

In the example below I have 2 other RadialGradientBrushes all sharing exactly the same properties except the GradientStops

I have already gone some way to inheriting, (See the STAC_RGrad_Status_Green) however is there a simpler way than this where I can replace all 4 Binding statements into a "One Liner" statement which is interpreted as

***Properties="{Binding Propterties , Source={DynamicResource STAC_RGrad_Status_Base}}    except GradientStops"***

Which will allow future proofing should I need to add an additional property to that tree of resources defined in

So instead of creating a binding for each property as I have done in the example
It is replaced by a "one liner"

### Existing Code

```
  <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="STAC_RGrad_Status_Base"
        GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
        Center="0.5,0.5"
        RadiusX="0.5" 
        RadiusY="0.5"
        GradientStops="{DynamicResource STAC_Grad_Status_Disabled}" 
     />



  <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="STAC_RGrad_Status_Red"
        GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
        Center="0.5,0.5"
        RadiusX="0.5" 
        RadiusY="0.5"
        GradientStops="{DynamicResource STAC_Grad_Status_Red}" 
     />

  <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="STAC_RGrad_Status_Green"
        GradientOrigin="{Binding GradientOrigin, Source={DynamicResource STAC_RGrad_Status_Base}}"
        Center="{Binding Center, Source={DynamicResource STAC_RGrad_Status_Base}}"
        RadiusX="{Binding RadiusX, Source={DynamicResource STAC_RGrad_Status_Base}}"
        RadiusY="{Binding RadiusY, Source={DynamicResource STAC_RGrad_Status_Base}}"
        GradientStops="{DynamicResource STAC_Grad_Status_Green}" 
 />
```

Comment: thx for that, yes typo, have updated original post

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there a simpler way than this where I can replace all 4 Binding statements into a "One Liner" statement which is interpreted as

Properties="{Binding Propterties , Source={DynamicResource STAC_RGrad_Status_Base}}       except GradientStops"

Comment: Why not turn it into an actual resource so then you can just use `BasedOn` to inherit everything you need from one source and only change the properties you need?